# Creating a method with unknown parameters in a class in typsescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, discord, bots

Me and my team are currently working on a discord bot project using discordjs and typescript. We made an event handler that works like this,
the main file scrolls through a folder `events\` and finds out the files with `.js` or `.ts` extensions. Then imports the file.

For example an ErrorEvent file looks like this,

```js
// file: src\events\ErrorEvent.ts

import CustomClient from "../libs/customClient";
import Event from "../libs/structure/event/Event";

export default class ErrorEvent extends Event {
  constructor(client:CustomClient ){
    super(client, "error");
  }
  run = async(error:string):Promise<void>=> {
    console.log("Discord client error!", error)
  }
}
```

in the above code the class Event is,

```js
// file: src\libs\structure\event\Event.ts
import CustomClient from "../../customClient";

export default class Event  {
  client:CustomClient;
  name:string;
  constructor(client:CustomClient, name:string) {
    this.client = client;
    this.name = name;
  }

  // a run method that has 1 parameter, error which is a string containing the error message
}
```

The event class constructor takes in two parameters, client and name of event. The name of event is different for each event.

But what I want to add is a method named run. This run method will be called when an event occurs. The run method should be defined in every subclass but not in the main class. But, the run methods parameters are going to be different with different types. For example,

MessageEvent -> Params = message:Message (Discord.Message)
ErrorEvent   -> Params = error:string    (String representing error)
etc.

I dont know how to make a method that allows different parameters for different functions. Also I want to link an interface with this class.

The interface file that I made, but produces errors when linked,

````js
// file: src\interface\EventInt.ts
import CustomClient from "../libs/customClient";

export default interface Events {
  client: CustomClient,
  name: string,
  run:(args:unknown) => void
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

What if the interface for your subclasses extend the interface for your base class. Something like:

```
interface Events {
    client: number,
    name: string,
}
// T will be the type for the run method
interface EventType<T> extends Events {
    run:(args: T) => void // You could use any but of course ...
}
```

That way, your base class could implement Events and all subclasses would implement and extension of Events.

```
export class Event implements Events {
    client: number;
    name:string;
    constructor(client:number, name:string) {
       this.client = client;
       this.name = name;
    }
}
class ErrorEvent extends Event implements EventType<string> {
    client = 4;
    name = "hello";
    run = async(error: string): Promise<void> => {
       console.log("Discord client error!", error)
    }    
}
```

If you want to pass multiple arguments, you could use a context object like so:

```
run = async({error, anotherError}: {error: string, anotherError: string[]}){}
```

Comment: This solution feels good. But here are the errors it produced.

This error was produced in class ErrorEvent which extends Event and implements EventType.

```Property 'run' in type 'ErrorEvent' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'EventType'.
  Type '(error: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(args: unknown) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'error' and 'args' are incompatible.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'```

Comment: Oh, I see. That's right, unknown can be any type. You could type args as any but if you really don't want to use any, then use a generic interface instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I will try it out soon.